# SQL Server Profiler monitor lock duration

Tags: sql-server, locking, sql-server-2000, sql-server-performance

I'm trying to monitor the duration of locks on my SQL Server, but the Duration column is blank.  How can I monitor this using Profiler?

Comment: Here is a good article about **how-to-identify-blocking-problems-with-sql-profiler** by **Brad McGehee** from [simple-talk.com](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/how-to-identify-blocking-problems-with-sql-profiler/)

Comment: You can also post this questions at the Database Administrators Exchange. http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Hiten004 -Unfortunately, that great article doesn't help me with SQL Server 2000 blocking issues.